# How do I partition and mount a 3TB Hard Disk using the terminal?

Tags: linux, partitioning, terminal, ubuntu-11.10

I have a 3TB  Hard disk which I wish to mount as a single partition under Ubuntu 11.10 server
Because it is over 2TB I know there are some issues with this. I'm unsure of what I need to do to make this happen.

I need to do this via the terminal because I am using the server edition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did it using these 2 apps:

- [`gdisk`](http://rodsbooks.com./gdisk/) (not `fdisk`) to create the initial partition, followed by
- the `mkfs.ext4` command from the `e2fsprogs` package to format it

Answer (score 22):

Use parted

it might be a bit complicated, so read up on the [internet (official manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_mono/parted.html) or `man parted`. Some commands to get started:

```
parted /dev/sdX     # substitute with your drive (and you prolly need sudo)
> mklabel gpt       # makes a new gpt partition table, afaik needed for >2TB
> mkpart pri 1 -1   # makes a new primary partition from start to end,
                    # note there are only primary partitions on gpt
```

afterwards format your partition, not exactly sure about the command in ubuntu, try

```
mkfs --type ext4 /dev/sdXY
```

for an ext4 partition.

That should suffice to make you able mount the partition.

Comment: parted does NOT support ext4 right now: File system type?  [ext2]? ext4                                           
No Implementation: Support for creating ext4 file systems is not implemented
yet.

Answer (score 2):

Use Gparted to partition & make a ext4 partition and you will be fine.

Comment: thank you for the recommendation but gparted is not accessable from the terminal